# Can channel bandwidth transmit any VALUES of frequencies as long as they are within range

Tags: communication

I know that channel bandwidth is the range of frequencies it can transmit . Let's say channel bandwidth is 100 Hz . Does that mean it can transmit any signal whose bandwidth is 100Hz regardless of actual values of those frequencies .
For example signal 1 has  frequencies 200Hz- 300Hz .
Signal 2 has frequencies 800Hz-900Hz.
Both signals have bandwidth 100Hz
Can the channel transmit both of these signals?

Comment: it depends on the carrier frequency and the modulation method, which you did not specify here.

Comment: Let's say I don't modulate the signals

Comment: then you have zero bandwidth.